# Removing time constrain from a list of dates and times in java

Tags: java, datetime

I have web table in which one of the columns has date and timestamp. I'm trying to achieve a list of only current dates, and also removing the timestamp from the same.

Here's the code I've written:

```
List<WebElement> colValues = new ArrayList<>();
colValues = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='v-table-table']//tbody//tr//td[17]"));
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
String string2 = String.valueOf(new ArrayList<String>());
for(WebElement e : colValues)
{
    strings.add(e.getText());
    System.out.println("Strings"+strings);
    string2 = String.valueOf(strings.size());
    for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        
    }
}
```

List elements: `[08/09/2022 06:44:09, 31/12/9999 00:00:00, 08/09/2022 06:40:17, 08/09/2022 06:37:48, 08/09/2022 04:52:42, 08/09/2022 04:49:36, 08/09/2022 06:07:56, 08/09/2022 05:08:55, 04/11/2019 22:02:35, 15/04/2019 13:13:55]`

Expected: remove timestamps and retrieve only today's date in list

Comment: So for each timestamp in the list, if its date is today’s date, retain it, otherwise discard it, is that it? Sorry, it’s not perfectly clear to me yet.

Comment: `strings.removeIf(s -> ! LocalDate.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/mm/uuuu HH:mm:ss")).equals(LocalDate.now()));` (will need refinement).

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line: `String string2 = String.valueOf(new ArrayList<String>());`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “removing the timestamp from the same”?  Do you mean to ignore the time-of-day? Edit your Question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the value of using only [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats when exchanging date-time values via text.

Also, educate the publisher about including an offset or time zone if the data is meant to represent a specific point on the timeline.

If changing to standard format is not an option, define a formatting pattern to fit your inputs.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) ;
```

Parse each input as a `LocalDateTime` object.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Determine today’s date. Doing so requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ; 
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Extract the date from each `LocalDateTime`, compare to today’s date.

```
if( ldt.toLocalDate().isEqual( today ) ) { … }
```

We can do the parsing and testing-for-today in a single statement using streams.

```
List < String > inputs = … ;
List < LocalDateTime > hits = 
    inputs
    .map(
        input -> LocalDateTime.parse( input , f )
    )
    .filter(
        ldt -> ldt.toLocalDate().isEqual( today )
    )
    .toList()
;
```